# Responsive content slider with jquery

Tags: slider, responsive-design, responsive-slides

I need responsive slider that can slide elements independently. This site http://www.youxithemes.com/live_previews/joiee/ has the slider that I need, but it seems they used revolution slider for wordpress. I am developing my own php website and can not use wordpress plugin. Is there any free slider like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best slider I found on the web to satisfy all my requirements is fractionslider

http://jacksbox.de/stuff/jquery-fractionslider/

Answer (score 0):

if you just need a responsive slider you could use the bootstrap one (carousel)
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#carousel

For independent elements slide, there's this one 
http://themes.themepunch.com/?theme=revolution_jq
I think it comes alone, without any wp stuff or theme.
Let me know if it's what you're looking for!

Comment: I found fraction slider to be best match to my needs: http://jacksbox.de/stuff/jquery-fractionslider/